# Firestore: Get multiple documents via complex fieldPath (where function)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I safed different products in my Firestore and they are available for purchase on different days of the week. So I safed the availability on different days as an Array of 7 boolean values in my Firestore.

```
weekdays = [true, true, true, false, false, true, false];
```

Now if I wanna get all products that are available on Friday I would have to do something like this:

```
// assume date.getDay() is 5

const q = query(
  collection(db, "bakerys", `${bakery.id}`, "products"), 
  where(`weekdays[${date.getDay()}]`, "==", "true")
);
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

This doesn't seem to work. Do I really have to store every weekday in its own value separately in order to make this work or is there a way to get this work differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store the days directly instead of a boolean value like this:

```
weekdays = ['Monday', 'Friday'];
```

Then execute this query:

```
const q = query(
  collection(db, "bakerys", `${bakery.id}`, "products"), 
  where(`weekdays`, "array-contains", "Monday")
);
```

This query will fetch all documents where the `weekdays` array contains `Monday`. If you want to store boolean values with day index then you would have to store a map like this:

```
weekdays = {
  1: true,
  5: false
}
```

Here you can use the following query:

```
const q = query(
  collection(db, "bakerys", `${bakery.id}`, "products"), 
  where(`weekdays.${date.getDay()}`, "==", true)
);
```

---

Additionally do note that your original array contains boolean values but your query had `"true"` (string). Make sure the types in db and query match.

Comment: Thanks, I think your second option is not possible tho as I just realised you get an error as return when trying to use "[" or "]" in the fieldPath. Also, when you try to enter the 1 of weekdays in your example (or other attrbutes), wouldn't you do it like this: weekdays['1'] and not like this: weekdays[1]? Thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: @Sumsidum correct my answer a bit. I missed the dot notation there in 2nd snippet